# How to access google spreadsheets with php in google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-docs-api, quercus

I have already PHP in GAE with Quercus, but I'm trying to access my google spreadsheets and I want to SELECT, INSERT INTO, UPDATE and also DELETE(or DROP, forgot the function) just like in mysql. How to do it??

Comment: Spreadsheets are not relational databases. What makes you think you should be able to use SQL commands with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably gonna need the library Google provides: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html